# Creating dictionary inside dictionary, list

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I have a data something like this:

```
[
('A','B','Z'),
('A','B','Y'),
('A','B','X'),
('A','C','Z'),
('A','C','Y'),
('A','C','X'),
('D','B','Z'),
('D','B','Y'),
('D','B','X')
]
```

Now I am trying to create a dictionary from it something like this:

```
basic_dict = {
    "A" : {
        "B" : ['Z','Y','X'],
        "C" : ['Z','Y','X']
    },
    "D" : {
        "B" : ['Z','Y','X']
    }
```

I wrote a code like below to achieve this but somehow I am not getting correct results:

```
basic_dict = {}
for i in data_list:
    url_list = []
    batchname_key = i[0]
    scrapid_key = i[1]
    for u in i[2]:
        url_list.append(u)
        basic_dict[batchname_key] = {scrapid_key : url_list}
```

> > > basic_dict
> > >       {'A': {'C': ['X']}, 'D': {'B': ['X']}}

The second problem in how can access this dict.

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate over `data_list` and append `url` to a sub-dict indexed by `scrapid_key` under a sub-dict indexed by `batchname_key` using the `dict.setdefault` method:

```
basic_dict = {}
for batchname_key, scrapid_key, url in data_list:
    basic_dict.setdefault(batchname_key, {}).setdefault(scrapid_key, []).append(url)
```

`basic_dict` becomes:

```
{'A': {'B': ['Z', 'Y', 'X'], 'C': ['Z', 'Y', 'X']}, 'D': {'B': ['Z', 'Y', 'X']}}
```